# Is there any way to convert SQL Server date time into format that be read by Google Sheet?

Tags: sql-server, regex, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas

So I just export SQL Server database and it contains date time data like this for example.

```
2018-02-16T05:55:37.720Z
2018-02-19T09:05:04.087Z
2018-03-11T14:16:40.150Z
2018-04-20T13:05:36.023Z
2018-12-26T15:43:58.077Z
2018-12-26T15:50:23.017Z
2018-12-26T15:59:13.150Z
2018-12-26T16:03:44.577Z
```

Is there any way to convert it to Google Sheet date time format?

Comment: What _is_ the Google format? Anyway, you might want to look into this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017#date-and-time-styles

Comment: I don't know but is the Google Sheet date time format without the `T` and `Z`?

Comment: Your sample are not SQL Server datetimes, they are strings (probably SQL Server varchars) containing dates in ISO 8601 format. If you tell us what format uses Google Sheet, we can help you converting those strings.

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have a format in SQL Server, they are stored as binary values. I would *expect* that if you pass that data as the correct data type (not a `varchar`), "Google" would interpret it correctly.

Comment: @MarcGuillot yes please, maybe it could help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(LEN(A1:A); TEXT(IFERROR(
 DATEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "(.*)T"))+
 TIMEVALUE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "T(.*)\."))); "dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm:ss"); ))
```

[image: 0]

---

or like this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(A1:A; "(.*)\."); "T"; " ")))
```

[image]

Comment: I got #ERROR! message

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1SL06KRcMf-qSQWIJy93J5grlAfzvBshvYlM0ELrX0Dw/edit?usp=sharing here it is